# Lua NPC door returning "Attempt to call a Instance Value"

Tags: lua, instance, roblox, path-finding

I want my code to have an interactable door by players, which works fine. However the code that makes the door open when an enemy NPC walks through a hitbox is not working. It tells me that 'attempt to call a Instance value' but I do not know how to fix it.

This is a section of my code so far

```
local Debounce = false
local Enemy = workspace.JUMPSCAREDUMMY


model.Hitbox.Touched:Connect(function(Object)
    if workspace.JUMPSCAREDUMMY(Object.Parent) then
        local Enemy = workspace.Enemy(Object.Parent)
        if Debounce == false then
            Debounce = true
            task.wait(1)
            leftTweenOpen:Play()
            rightTweenOpen:Play()
            prompt.ActionText = "Close"
            task.wait(2)
            leftTweenClose:Play()
            rightTweenClose:Play()
            prompt.ActionText = "Open"
            task.wait(2)
            Debounce = false
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: Why do you call it? E.g., what do you expect from `workspace.JUMPSCAREDUMMY(Object.Parent)`?

Comment: I call `workspace.JUMPSCAREDUMMY(Object.Parent)` to make sure that the hitbox only opens for the NPC, not players, and it that line of code should make sure that it is inside the hitbox

Comment: What is `JUMPSCAREDUMMY`? Can you link me the definition of it (specifically the __call) and explain why you are certain that this works? I'm not very familiar with Roblox but calling an instance, and I assume `JUMPSCAREDUMMY` is an instance, seems invalid to me. Maybe you meant `workspace.JUMPSCAREDUMMY[Object.Parent]`, but even that is odd.